# Reference request - binary cubic forms and integral points on elliptic curves of $j$-invariant 0

Tags: nt.number-theory

I've heard that integral solutions to equations of the form $y^2 = x^3 + a$ for $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ yield binary cubic forms of discriminant related to $a$.

Where can I find a reference for this?

Answer (score 5):

This connection is outlined on page 246 of Mordell's book "Diophantine Equations". More explicit details can be found at
https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/CB62147F66768E3777082ABC1DBFCE27/S1461157015000182a.pdf/mordells_equation_a_classical_approach.pdf